# Kv language doesn't see the file in the directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I have textures for my buttons grouped in a folder `textures\button` (relative to the code file). Throughout my code, I have specified this path in several places, in the kv and in Python code. The Python code seemed to recognize the textures just fine, while the kv failed to find them. What's up with that?
Here is the code sample:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string('''
<MyButton>:
    background_normal: "textures\\button\\normal.png"
''')

class MyButton(Button):
    pass

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        bt = MyButton()
        return bt

TestApp().run()
```

This gave me a blank texture. However, when I removed the kv part and built my button like that:

```
bt = MyButton(background_normal = "textures\\button\\normal.png")
```

the texture appeared.
I'm using Kivy `v1.9.2-dev0`

Comment: Have you tried using "textures/button/normal.png" in your kv instead of the path you have now (i.e., change the slashes)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace the `\\` in your path with `/`, i.e., use:

```
Builder.load_string('''
<MyButton>:
    background_normal: "textures/button/normal.png"
''')
```

In my experience, kv expects paths to be in the format shown above, and if this works for you I will assume that this is a platform independent expectation of kivy.

Comment: I'm using Windows and the path is delimited by backslashes, so I would assume the same applied to Kivy, apparently not

Comment: @Leva7 Got it, thanks for the info! I haven't done any development on Windows yet so I am not very familiar with the conventions.

Comment: Kivy is cross-platform, so we try to avoid making people write platform-specific code. Every other platform Kivy runs on uses `/` as the path delimiter, so that's the standard.

Comment: When I try using / in Windows it won't work for me in the kivy file

Comment: @user2067030 can you be more specific about what you are trying and what the result is?